# Different between of(...) and [...] in switchMap in effect

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx, switchmap, angular-redux

For example we have some effect:

```
...
switchMap(() => of(action1, action2))
...
```

and

```
...
switchMap(() => [action1, action2])
...
```

Do we have any differents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is correct.

The first approach are 2 emits, which would notify all subscribers multiple times.

Comment: actually, if you return an array, it will use `from()` which will also be two emits. Practically there is no difference between the two options